# Always execute Setup with Administrator privileges

Tags: inno-setup, admin-rights

We have a Setup-File built with Inno-Setup. We often have to deploy a new Version to our customer. 
The System-Administrator of our customer has asked me if there is any possibility to configure our setup that a normal user is able to execute it. He dont want to give admin rights to his users but he wants his users to be able to execute our setup-file!

Our Setup needs admin privileges. So the Option for

```
Privileges required = lowest
```

in Inno-Setup is not a solution.

So is there any possibility that the system-admin of our customer gives us a script or something else in order to get admin rights automatically? Only for our setup-file? Our setup could call this batchfile before installation to get admin rights.

Comment: What a chicken-egg problem. Well, if you deploy your setup with `admin` privileges, then you must run it elevated. And I don't think you can grant an exception for this. I can imagine that the admin will run the setup remotely, or you write a service application that will elevate your setup on the client, or you deploy with the `lowest` privileges having granted access to resources where you write. But this question is not about Inno Setup anymore. It is a Windows administration question and as such better fits to http://superuser.com/.